# Await inside an await doesn't give correct output

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ethereum, web3js

Below is my code where I want to check if a token exists. If yes, then I will check if the wallet owner is the token owner. Problem now is it doesn't check the second function "contract.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call(function (err, res)" thus the final result is not the correct outcome.

```
async function doesTokenIdExist(tokenId, contract, walletAddress) {
    var tokenExists = false;
    await contract.methods.exists(tokenId).call(async function (err, res) {
        if (res) {
            await contract.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call(function (err, res) {
                if (!err) {
                    tokenAddress = res.toLowerCase();
                    walletAddress = walletAddress.toLowerCase();
                    
                    if (tokenAddress.localeCompare(walletAddress) == 0){
                        tokenExists = true;
                    } else {
                        tokenExists = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    tokenExists = false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            tokenExists = false;
        }
    });
    
    return tokenExists;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this,

```
await contract.methods.exists(tokenId).call(function (err, res) {
```

to this,

```
await contract.methods.exists(tokenId).call(async function (err, res) {
```

Comment: It works. But now I have another problem. When the nested await function returns true, the entire function still returns false.

Comment: You need to debug the code. Try sequence of console.log for every if else and see how your code executes.